# mongoexport CSV output format

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

I am running mongoexport using:

```
mongoexport ... --fields _id, Field1
```

which results in:

```
{"_id":"someId1","Field1":false}
{"_id":"someId2","Field1":true}
```

I would prefer to obtain a "standard" CSV output:

```
_id, Field1
someId1, false
someId2, true
```

But I was unable to find an appropriate parameter of mongoexport.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name --type=csv --fields _id,Field1 --out /dir/backups/myCollection.csv
```

If You're using an earlier version (mongodb 2.6) then first create a file named fields : 
**fields.txt**

`_id`

`Field1`

Then use this :

```
mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name --csv --fieldFile fields.txt --out /dir/backups/myCollection.csv
```

Comment: It seems that --type made all the difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
mongoexport -u admin -p password --host hostdirection -d databasename -c collection--authenticationDatabase admin -f "_id,Field1"  -o outputfile.csv
```

Comment: What does it do? Explain it in your post.